# vb.net Sort Chart By X Axis Date

Tags: mysql, vb.net, sorting, date, charts

I have a chart where months are labelled on the x axis and the y values are integers.

```
Private MonthProfit As SortedDictionary(Of String, Integer) = New SortedDictionary(Of String, Integer)

Private Sub frmChart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Query As String = "SELECT Profit, SaleDate FROM tblpayment"

        Using Conn As New MySqlConnection(MySQL.ConnectionDetails)
            Using Comm As New MySqlCommand()
                With Comm
                    .Connection = Conn
                    .CommandText = Query
                    .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                End With
                Try
                    Conn.Open()
                    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader = Comm.ExecuteReader
                    While Reader.Read OrElse (Reader.NextResult And Reader.Read)
                        If MonthProfit.ContainsKey(MonthName(Reader.GetDateTime(1).Month)) Then
                            MonthProfit(MonthName(Reader.GetDateTime(1).Month)) += Reader.GetInt32(0)
                        Else
                            MonthProfit.Add(MonthName(Reader.GetDateTime(1).Month), 0)
                            MonthProfit(MonthName(Reader.GetDateTime(1).Month)) += Reader.GetInt32(0)
                        End If
                    End While
                Catch ex As MySqlException

                End Try
            End Using
        End Using

        For Each index In MonthProfit.ToArray
            'chMain.Series.Add(index.Key)
            chMain.Series("Profit").Points.AddXY(index.Key, index.Value)
        Next
        chMain.Series("Profit").Sort(pointSortOrder:=DataVisualization.Charting.PointSortOrder.Ascending, sortBy:="Axislabel")

    End Sub
```

I cant seem to figure how to do this, so I would appreciate some help to point me towards the right direction.

---

FIXED SOLUTION:

```
Private Sub frmChart_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim Query As String = "SELECT MONTHNAME(SaleDate) AS MonthName, Profit FROM tblpayment ORDER BY SaleDate ASC"

    Using Conn As New MySqlConnection(MySQL.ConnectionDetails)
        Using Comm As New MySqlCommand()
            With Comm
                .Connection = Conn
                .CommandText = Query
                .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            End With
            Try
                Conn.Open()
                Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader = Comm.ExecuteReader
                While Reader.Read OrElse (Reader.NextResult And Reader.Read)
                    If MonthProfit.ContainsKey(Reader.GetString(0)) Then
                        MonthProfit(Reader.GetString(0)) += Reader.GetInt32(1)
                    Else
                        MonthProfit.Add(Reader.GetString(0), 0)
                        MonthProfit(Reader.GetString(0)) += Reader.GetInt32(1)
                    End If
                End While
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.GetBaseException.ToString)
            End Try
        End Using
    End Using

    For Each index In MonthProfit.ToArray
        chMain.Series(0).Points.AddXY(index.Key, index.Value)
    Next

    chMain.Series(0).XValueMember = "Month Name"
    chMain.Series(0).YValueMembers = "Profit"
    chMain.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1

End Sub
```

Comment: You can simply add sorting to your query.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Could you help me out a bit more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add sorting to the query, Also you can use a `DataTable` and `TableAdapter` and use data-binding to your chart this way:

```
Dim ConnectionString As String = "your connection string"
Dim CommandText As String = "SELECT Profit, MONTHNAME(SaleDate) AS MonthName " & _
                            "FROM tblpayment ORDER BY SaleDate ASC"
Dim Adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(CommandText, ConnectionString)
Dim Table As New DataTable()
Adapter.Fill(Table)

Me.Chart1.Series(0).XValueMember = "MonthName"
Me.Chart1.Series(0).YValueMembers = "Profit"
Me.Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1
Me.Chart1.DataSource = Table
Me.Chart1.DataBind()
```

Comment: Ok thanks for helping. However, it doesnt work as I want it to. If the month already exists as an x value, i want it to add the value in profit to that month. Thats the problem I found with your code. However, I took your query and tried it in my code like this and it didnt seem to make any difference: http://pastebin.com/hu8894vi Sorry I had to do a pastebin link as you can't add code in a comment.

Comment: @Semonoir **If the month already exists as an x value, i want it to add the value in profit to that month.** It is not what your code perform nor you said in the main question :) But you can use group by and sum for that.

Comment: My code did say that: MonthProfit(MonthName(Reader.GetDateTime(1).Month)) += Reader.GetInt32(0). I implied it by the += but I should have been more clear. Anyways thanks for your help I shall try and continue.

Comment: You can leave it just in case anyone in the future has a similar problem.

Comment: I realised my mistake. The dictionary was a sorted dictionary so it was automatically sorting the keys into alphabetical order. -_- . Your query helped anyways, thanks.